# Joomla! display article based on URL in stead of 404 page

Tags: php, joomla, joomla1.7

We have a website based on Joomla! in the joomla directory, there are many other directories, i.e.:

```
C:\myjoomlawebsite
  ...joomla directories...
  \myspecialdirectory
```

in "myspecialdirectory" there are resources that sometimes are available and other times are not available, as one would imagine, when a resource(php page) is not available, a 404 page is displayed.

What I would like to do is, "somehow" tell joomla that when the user tries to access a page located in "myspecialdirectory" and it's unavailable, it should show an article page rather than a 404.

- if the user accesses mydomain.com/ <- all good
- if the user accesses mydomain.com/existingpage.php <- all good
- if the user accesses mydomain.com/unavailablepage.php <- a 404 should be shown
- if the user accesses mydomain.com/myspecialdirectory/existingpage.php <- all good
- if the user accesses mydomain.com/myspecialdirectory/unavilablepage.php <- here's where I want the user to see a article page in stead of a 404

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_Custom_404_Error_Page)

For v1.5

```
if (($this->error->code) == '404') {
header('Location: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=75');
exit;
}
```

For 1.6 & 1.7

```
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
```

Comment: This isn't going to work because `myspecialdirectory` is outside of the Joomla framework.

Comment: @Rikesh thank you, the header trick worked perfectly, but my condition was based on JURI getPath(), I've searched that instance based on requirements and the set the header location to where I needed

Answer (score 0):

Because that directory is outside of the Joomla framework, and you only want one directory to redirect to a Joomla page instead of a 404, then the easiest way to accomplish this is to use put a custom htaccess in the directory you want to redirect. You would want to add this to htaccess only in `myspecialdirectory`

```
ErrorDocument 404 /URL TO JOOMLA ARTICLE.php
```

Answer (score 0):

For the standards-compliant solutions -- take a read here: http://magazine.joomla.org/component/k2/item/230